# Can I mark a property as "not to be serialized" when using the BinaryFormatter?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a c# class I want to mark as `[Serializable]` but it has a property that I don't want serialized:

```
    public object atlas
    {
        get
        {
            return _atlas;
        }
        set
        {
            // some code here
        }
    }
```

I can't just slap `[NonSerializable]` on it because that only works for member fields, not for properties. Currently, it looks like I need to implement `ISerializable` and override the contstructor that takes `SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context` as arguments and the `GetObjectData` method.

This will be cumbersome, and will cause other complications with the deserialization.

Comment: Just explicitly fill out the property and have it modify a `[NonSerializable]` field.

Comment: I'm working in someone else's codebase. Was hoping I wouldn't have to change their code style.

Comment: Properties do not get serialized, only fields.  You want the attribute on _atlas.

Comment: Are you sure? I just put `public int AnotherInt { get; set; }` into a serialized class, and upon deserializing, the value changed. FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(MyType) shows AnotherInt in the returned list of members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tag your backing field `_atlas` with `[NonSerializable]`.